# SAPgui script with variables values from Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript, sap-gui

I need to populate dates on fields in SAP which if manually entered is properly captured by the script recorder.

Is it possible to update the script dates using a cell link in Excel?

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtLKO74-PERIO").Text = "2"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtLKO74-BUPERIO").Text = "2"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtLKO74-GJAHR").Text = "2016"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtLKO74-BZDAT").Text = "29.02.2016"
```

I plan to copy the recorded SAP script and incorporate it in an Excel macro as a button.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbook = app.Workbooks.Open("c:\tmp\prices.xls")
set sheet = wbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtLKO74-PERIO").Text = sheet.Cells(1,2).Value 
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtLKO74-BUPERIO").Text = sheet.Cells(1,3).Value 
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtLKO74-GJAHR").Text = sheet.Cells(1,4).Value 
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtLKO74-BZDAT").Text = sheet.Cells(1,5).Value
```

Get App object, then get workbook and worksheet objects, and then assign your script cell values.

Answer (score -1):

Everything is well discussed here including all the comments asking for different scenarios. https://scn.sap.com/thread/1699675

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here